# Multiple pageview submissions to google analytics

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I have an odd situation where I have to track a pageview more than once on a page.

There is a dynamic search bar where it suggests products as you type. The problem is if they click an option from the suggested list, GA doesn't track the words they typed into the search bar to reach that result. I have written some jQuery that calls 'ga()' when they click the suggested link:

```
ga('send', 'pageview', '/?s=' + $(".product-search-field").val() + '&post_type=product');
```

But this snippet does not seem to track anything. I have a feeling it's something to do calling a send command a second time but I can't find much info on this.

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: There is no problem with triggering multiple pageview calls per page. Are you sure that the ga call is triggered at all ? If you are on Chrome install the Google Analytics debugger extension, this will show if data is sent and what it looks like.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I know it _reaches_ that line of code but unsure if the ga() function actually does anything. I will download that plugin and see if it can offer me any more info.

Comment: Ok, now we're getting somewhere! I am getting this error: `Uncaught ReferenceError: ga is not defined` - I call the method at the very bottom of the page, it's basically the last thing before `</body>`, after all of the Google scripts are already imported. Any ideas why it says it's not defined?

Comment: Really hard to say without any context - is it possible to look at your site ? It is possible to rename the ga function, but that's nothing ones does by accident so I don't think this is what happened here.

Comment: I think I've actually managed to fix it! Your suggestion for the debugger allowed me to get that error, then with a bit of research I found out that I had to reference the function via `window.ga` due to it being inside of another function. Thanks for suggesting that tool though :)